# How do I kill time?

Tags: treasure-adventure-game

In [Treasure Adventure Game](http://www.robitstudios.com/treasure-adventure-game/), there are numerous locations that are only accessible at certain times of the day. I always seem to be at the wrong end of the day when I'm ready for these events, and often just spend the remainder of the game day twiddling my thumbs and generally being bored.

## I find this unacceptable.

Is there anyway I can sleep, sit on a bench, or generally move forward through time in a quicker manner?

Comment: am i the only one who thought this question might have been about some sort of boss?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you get the Magic Bottle, you **can** fast-forward time by going to an alternate dimension.

You may have noticed these black holes all over the place. (I was initially [confused about them](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59382/what-is-this-strange-swirly-vortex-thing), too.)

[image: black hole]

You can scoop these up with your bottle, then release them to open a portal to said dimension. It serves 2 purposes:

1. **Fast travel**. You can walk across the ocean and press up to warp to the island you're standing on.
2. **Time travel!** Time goes a lot faster in this dimension. Just wait for the sun/moon to be in the position you want, then warp out.

Comment: Wow, this is great! Gone are the days of my loitering around the park to while away the time!

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly from my playthrough, there is no way to do so.  That really frustrated me too.  Have a website ready to alt-tab to; StackOverflow is one excellent candidate.

Don't give up on it entirely because of this.  There's not too many time-sensitive events, and except for a few annoying glitches and design flaws, the game plays very well.